# Simple Form - Devise Sign Up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, simple-form

I have Rails Devise Bootstrap and Simple Form.

My devise registration/sign-up form is in a bootstrap modal. It is a simple form.

When I click on the register link (from my navbar) on my root url, the form works fine. When I navigate to another page and click that link, the simple form fields are blank. The form boxes are there to fill in, but the text above them that describe the field, are missing.

Any ideas? Thank you

This is my form:

```
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-inputs" style="padding-left:15%; text-align:left;">
        <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions" style="padding-left:15%; padding-top:5%; text-align:left;">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Register" %><% end %>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add above each "f.input .." field a "f.label :insert_field_name_here", and it should work.

Comment: Hi Claudiu, do you mean to substitute the name of the field after the colon? As in f.label:insert_first_name_here? I tried both ways, but not getting it to work in this structure, e.g.:  <%= f.label :insert_field_name_here f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>

Comment: try <%= f.label :first_name %> <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %> etc..

Answer (score 0):

Really strange, but that text was formatted white in the sub pages. Not sure why, but mystery solved.